# Odoo V10 - Calculated field

Tags: python, odoo

**Here is my calculated field:**

```
half_pension_days_value = fields.Integer(string='Day value', copy=False, compute='convert_bin_dec')
```

**Here is my function:**

```
@api.multi
def convert_bin_dec(self):
    if self.half_pension:
        print "Je suis dans la fonction convert"
        self.half_pension_days_value = 5
```

**Encountered problem :**

As soon as I launch this function thanks to the state of my boolean `half_pension`, my print starts looping.
I guess the problem is at this line -> `self.half_pension_days_value = 5`.

But why ?

**EDIT :** 
In order

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    record = super(ResPartnerSchool, self).create(vals)
    record.convert_bin_dec()
    return record


@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    result = super(ResPartnerSchool, self).write(vals)
    self.convert_bin_dec()
    return result
```

Here my error -> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the following : the `convert_bin_dec()` method calls the `write()` method of your object when you do this : `self.half_pension_days_value = 5` and the `write()` method calls again the `convert_bin_dec()` method, so you have recursive calls.

To fix this kind of issue, you have to use the `@api.depends` decorator.

Try with this :

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('half_pension')
def convert_bin_dec(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.half_pension:
            print "Je suis dans la fonction convert"
            record.half_pension_days_value = 5
```

Do not forget to remove the `self.convert_bin_dec()` in the `write()`and `create()` methods.

Comment: Thanks You ! I have solved my problem with this solution

Answer (score 1):

Hennion,

You said that half_pension is your boolean field. Then try this code:

```
@api.multi
def convert_bin_dec(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.half_pension == True:
            print "Je suis dans la fonction convert"
            rec.half_pension_days_value = 5
```

`or` You can break your function.it limit multiple entries.

```
@api.multi
def convert_bin_dec(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.half_pension:
            print "Je suis dans la fonction convert"
            rec.half_pension_days_value = 5
            break
```